# How do I get HTTP web request to return complete source

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I am trying to retrieve source code for a webpage and I'm using HTTPWebRequest but only this is returned:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    window.location="index.php"; 
</script>
```

I used fiddler to get a comparison of chrome getting the webpage and compared it with my what my code retrieves.

Chrome is on the left and VS code on the right

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hgk9w.png

What I've noticed is that the content length is no where as large as what chrome gets back. My code content length is usually around 70 bites and chrome gets back 87000 bites usually.

I have tried using Stream, and memory stream. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Here is my function below:

```
public string GetAllCampaings()
{
    string campaigns = null;
    byte[] result;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

    HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest2 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://magiclampmarketing.com/sms/manage_groups.php");
    httpWebRequest2.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
    httpWebRequest2.Method = "GET";
    httpWebRequest2.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
    httpWebRequest2.KeepAlive = true;
    httpWebRequest2.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11";
    httpWebRequest2.Referer = "http://magiclampmarketing.com/sms/main.php";
    httpWebRequest2.SendChunked = false;

    WebHeaderCollection myWebHeaderCollection = httpWebRequest2.Headers;
    myWebHeaderCollection.Add("Accept-Language", "en;q=0.8");
    myWebHeaderCollection.Add("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3");
    myWebHeaderCollection.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate,sdch");

    var sp = httpWebRequest2.ServicePoint;
    var prop = sp.GetType().GetProperty("HttpBehaviour", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    prop.SetValue(sp, (byte)0, null);

    using (WebResponse response = httpWebRequest2.GetResponse())
    {
        using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                int count = 0;
                do
                {
                    count = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, count);
                    memoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);

                } while (count != 0);

                result = memoryStream.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }

    return campaigns; 
}
```

Comment: All that javascript which is being returned is doing is redirecting the browser instantly to `index.php`.  So you're correctly reading the content of the page, it's just not what you're expecting it to be.

Comment: Is there anyway for me to get the content of page anyways even though the javascript is being run? Or httpwebrequests dont handle javascripts? Is there a way for me to get the source of the page as If I opened chrome/IE/Firefox went to the page, logged in and did view page source?

Comment: Try turning off javascript in your browser, then visiting the page and looking at the source.  See what that gives you.  But yes, HttpWebRequest doesn't handle javascript at all.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the chrome browser you are using is already logged into that site and has a session cookie.
However your code does not highlight how you are passing the session cookie.

From what is seen, it looks like the request from your program is coming back with a response that is redirecting you to login page.

You either have to clarify your take on passing the session cookie. Or accept that your programming is doing what it is expected to do.

Comment: I already logged into the page programatically and have the session cookie, its just here when I request the source of this specific page with the session cookie I only get back that <script type="text/javascript"> 
    window.location="index.php"; 
</script>

Comment: @KeithDrummond - Request `index.php` instead of the page you're currently asking for.  That's what it's redirecting you to, after all.

Comment: Ok, I think whats happening is the page im requesting is all javascript. Is there a way for me to get the source of page regardless of javascript that needs to run?

Comment: @KeithDrummond - definitely the page you are requesting is not all javascript and the program you have written in working good. The only part you have clarify or re evaluate is the part of code that sets the cookie container. I have no idea how are reusing a session cookie and it is a sensitive section. You are technically mimicking a browser. Revisit the code that determines the cookie container or ask another question in detail about that.